# Color difference in moderncv and moderntimeline

Tags: color, moderncv, moderntimeline

I'm playing around with the `moderncv` and `moderntimeline` package to create my CV. However, if I specifiy that `moderntimelinecv` should be in blue the color dosn't match with the blue from the `moderncv` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\tlwidth{0.8ex}
\tltext{\tiny}

\tllabelcventry[blue]{1999}{2000}{1999--2000}{Paramedic}
{\href{http://www.croix-rouge.fr/}{French Red Cross}}{Paris Suburbs}{}
{Served in several volunteer missions as a paramedic}
```

[image]

Is there a way that both are the blue from `moderncv`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: `\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue`

Comment: Thanks Johannes_B. I saw that in the .sty file. However, it didn't change the color of modentimeline if I added the values there. If i specified light blue instead of blue the file didn't compile.

Comment: Can’t you just use `color1` in the timeline? It has been defined in the .sty already.

Comment: Dang! The solution was right there and I didn't see it. Thank you @JasperHabicht. That did the trick.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Do you want to write up a quick answer?

Answer (score 1):

As Johannes_B points out, “light blue” is already defined in the sty file that is loaded via `\moderncvcolor{blue}` as

```
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue
```

So, you just can use this color in your document, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\tlwidth{0.8ex}
\tltext{\tiny}

\tllabelcventry[color1]{1999}{2000}{1999--2000}{Paramedic} % change blue to color1 here
{\href{http://www.croix-rouge.fr/}{French Red Cross}}{Paris Suburbs}{}
{Served in several volunteer missions as a paramedic}

...
```